# После авторизации не происходит редирект на главную страницу

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Прем здравствуйте, впервые делаю авторизацию,  использую нод, монгодб и экспресс, все подключила, токен записывается в кукис, и теперь надо сделать, чтобы после логина открывалась следующая страница, а у меня остается страница с формой. Я нашла как это выполнить если токен хранится в local storage, но не знаю, как подстроить это с кукис, и вообще не уверена, правильно ли я делаю или нет.
Возможно вопрос глупый, но я только учусь. Буду рада любой информации, большое спасибо!
Ссылка на гит: https://github.com/daryalewy/kickstarter-app

Auth.js

```
import useToken from "../Components/useToken";


export default function Auth() {
  const Body = styled.section`
    min-height: 550px;
    min-width: 319.98px;
    background: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgba(213, 189, 238, 1) 0%,
      rgba(166, 124, 232, 1) 100%
    );
    padding-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
  `;

  const { token, setToken } = useToken();

  if (!token) {
    return (
      <>
        <Body>
          <Logo />
          <Login setToken={setToken} />
        </Body>
        <Socials />
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <MainPage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

useToken.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.token
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

Routes in backend

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!isEmail(email)) {
      throw new Error('Email must be a valid email address.');
    }
    if (typeof password !== 'string') {
      throw new Error('Password must be a string.');
    }
    const user = new User({ email, password });
    const persistedUser = await user.save();
    const userId = persistedUser._id;

    const session = await initSession(userId);

    res
      .cookie('token', session.token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        maxAge: 1209600000,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      })
      .status(201)
      .json({
        title: 'User Registration Successful',
        detail: 'Successfully registered new user',
        csrfToken: session.csrfToken,
      });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      errors: [
        {
          title: 'Registration Error',
          detail: 'Something went wrong during registration process.',
          errorMessage: err.message,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
});

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!isEmail(email)) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: [
          {
            title: 'Bad Request',
            detail: 'Email must be a valid email address',
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    if (typeof password !== 'string') {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: [
          {
            title: 'Bad Request',
            detail: 'Password must be a string',
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    const userId = user._id;

    const passwordValidated = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!passwordValidated) {
      throw new Error();
    }

    const session = await initSession(userId);

    res
      .cookie('token', session.token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
        maxAge: 1209600000,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      })
      .json({
        title: 'Login Successful',
        detail: 'Successfully validated user credentials',
        csrfToken: session.csrfToken,
      });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({
      errors: [
        {
          title: 'Invalid Credentials',
          detail: 'Check email and password combination',
          errorMessage: err.message,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API

Редирект на главную осуществляется на фронте.